# Symfony2 - pass custom set of data to choice field view

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

I have a custom view for choice field in Symfony2 form. Except for value and label, it needs one more parameter for each choice.

View goes basically like this:

```
{% block mycustomfield_widget %}
    <div>
        {% for value, choice in choices %}
            <div>
                <i class="{{ choice.icon }}"></i>
                <input type="radio" value="{{ value }}">
                <h3>{{ choice.text }}</h3>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And I am trying to pass data like this:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'expanded' => true,
        'choices' => array(
            'value1' => array(
                'icon' => 'myIcon1',
                'text' => 'myText1'
            ),
            'value2' => array(
                'icon' => 'myIcon2',
                'text' => 'myText2'
            ),
        )
    ));
}
```

Unfortunately for me it seems, that Symfony2 is interpreting this like input for grouped radiobuttons.

```
{{ dump(choice) }} yields following:

array(2) { [0]=> object(Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\View\ChoiceView)#1223 (3) {    ["data"]=> string(4) "icon" ["value"]=> string(4) "icon" ["label"]=> string(14) "myIcon1" } [1]=> object(Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\View\ChoiceView)#1224 (3) { ["data"]=> string(4) "text" ["value"]=> string(4) "text" ["label"]=> string(14) "myText1" } } 
array(2) { [0]=> object(Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\View\ChoiceView)#1223 (3) { ["data"]=> string(4) "icon" ["value"]=> string(4) "icon" ["label"]=> string(14) "myIcon2" } [1]=> object(Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\View\ChoiceView)#1224 (3) { ["data"]=> string(4) "text" ["value"]=> string(4) "text" ["label"]=> string(14) "myText2" } }
```

What are my options to pass more then one parameter for rendering to each choice?
I've googled a lot, but all solutions seems either like hacking, or require creation of class that extends ChoiceList, which seems like overkill.
Are there any simplier solution for such a task?

Comment: Can you explain what you want your output to look like and what it looks like now?

Comment: @HaigBedrosian: problem is not about look of the output. Right now it looks like "Symfony: Exception Detected" because there is no way to pass multiple params into each choice.

Comment: In order to provide an answer to your question (ie is there a simpler way), it would be helpful to know what you want to achieve. You may just be going about things the wrong way and trying to force a square peg in a round hole.